# R styler addin: how to setup?

Tags: r, coding-style

I am using the R styler addin (https://github.com/r-lib/styler) to correct the coding style.
The illustration shown in the githib page shows a straighforward way to apply the style to the code.
Though, when I click the 'style active file" nothing happens.
I though that we would have to setup the styling function, but I am not able to do so.

Has anyone correctly use this addin before, that could hint on how to set it up correclty?

Comment: You should have a look at the following link: - https://styler.r-lib.org/articles/styler.html

Comment: It's designed to work in RStudio. Maybe you need to restart the IDE after installation. Also, check the R prompt for messages and outputs. Note that for `styler < 1.5.1`, this prompt [might ask you on first time usage to create a permanent cache with R.cache](https://github.com/dreamRs/esquisse/issues/168). This won't happen with [`styler >= 1.5.1`](https://github.com/r-lib/styler/pull/819), so please update in that case.

Comment: Restarting the computer solved it.